# Get JFrame in ActionListener that is placed on a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, propertychangelistener

How do I get `JFrame` in `ActionListener` that is placed on a `JMenuItem`?

```
public class justAJFrame extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener
      jMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              try {

                  swingWorkerInstance.addPropertyChangeListener(/*Here needs to be my justAJFrame */);
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use justAJFrame.this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

justAJFrame.this

thankx to MadProgrammer